# How to convert Caffe weights to Keras

Tags: keras, caffe

Is there a good way or a tool to convert `.caffemodel` weight files to HDF5 files that can be used with Keras?

I don't care so much about converting the Caffe model definitions, I can easily write those in Keras manually, I'm just interested in getting the trained weights out of that Caffe binary protocol buffer format and into the Keras format. I'm not a Caffe user, i.e. not very familiar with it.

Comment: This Caffe-to-Keras converter is what you're looking for: https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/caffe_weight_converter